# Percentage height of child in CSS

Tags: css, cross-browser

I am trying to set the height of a child element as a percentage of its parent. 
Here is my set up:

```
    .html, .body {height: 100%; width: 100%}
        /* test is a child of body to ensure content is aligned in the middle */
    .test {
        width: 90%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 5%;
        top: 0%;
        margin: -0% 0 0 0%;
     }
     /* top banner */
    .banner { 
      height: 100px;
      margin-left: 2%;
      width: 96%;
    }
    /* rest of the content */
    .center{
       background-color: #FFFFFF;
       height: 80%;
       margin-left: 2%;
       margin-top: 10px;
       overflow-x: auto;
       padding: 3px;
       position: relative;
       width: 95%;
   }
   /* content inside center */
   .iwant-event {
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      width: 84.5%;
   }
```

One would expect that the iwant-event class to fill 100% of the center. In chrome, I get this behavior. However, in Firefox, iwant-event does not fill 100% of the center. A simplified version of my HTML is:

```
<body>
  <div class="test">
     <div class="banner">Banner stuff here</div>
     <div class="center">
        <div class="iwant-event"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am fairly conversant with basic CSS, but have never tried developing for many browsers before. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this page get rendered in quirks or in strict mode? There's quite a bit of difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it doesn't work in FF? Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mZ3Vp/1/ works fine on my machine. If it doesn't work for you, could you specify what OS you're on and what version of FF are you using?

Comment: Let me try that and get back to you. I have changed other classes since. I will probably fiddle my entire code and share teh link.

Answer (score 0):

> One would expect that the iwant-event class to fill 100% of the center.

What is not happening exactly? Do you want `iwant-event` to fill the container horizontally and vertically? It does fill it vertically as far as I can see. Horizontally it does not because you have the rule:

```
.iwant-event { 
  width: 84.5%;
}
```

You need to change this to...

```
.iwant-event { 
  width: 100%;
}
```

...for full horizontal filling. And of course you have 3px of padding on `center` as well, so you need to remove this to get `iwant-event` to completely fill `center`.